# How do I mix typed and untyped actors?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-http, akka-typed

How do I mix typed and untyped actors ? As I understood I have to specify main actor when I create instance of `ActorSystem` like this

```
val system: akka.typed.ActorSystem[Start] = akka.typed.ActorSystem("main", Props(mainBehaviour))
```

On the other hand I use akka-http which is initialized like this

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
// etc...
```

I see that I can create typed system from untyped system by calling

```
object ActorSystem {
  def apply(untyped: akka.actor.ActorSystem): ActorSystem[Nothing] = new Wrapper(untyped.asInstanceOf[ExtendedActorSystem])
}
```

So assuming I did

```
val typeSystem = akka.typed.ActorSystem(untypedSystem)
```

how do I create my first typed actor from `typeSystem` ? There is no typed `ActorContext` whose `actorOf` I can call.

Other materials I've read on the subject are

- http://blog.scalac.io/2015/04/30/leszek-akka-typed.html
- http://www.slideshare.net/ktoso/fresh-from-the-oven-042015-experimental-akka-typed-and-akka-streams
- https://github.com/rubendg/innovation-day-akka-typed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch, this is currently not conveniently possible: what you would need to do is to create the typed ActorSystem and then access the underlying untyped one in order to start the HTTP extension, but the `underlying` method is `private[akka]`. You could access this by placing some helper code in your project within the Akka namespace, or you could go the other way around:

```
implicit val untyped = akka.actor.ActorSystem("main")
import untyped.dispatcher
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

import akka.typed.Ops._
val typedRef = untyped.spawn(Props(mainBehaviour))
val typedSys = ActorSystem(untyped)

Http().bind(...) // and send things to typed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works but whole thing looks quite unfriendly because of name clashes. I had to write `AskPattern.Askable(typedRef).?(Start)`.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the imports, please open an issue on github so that we can properly fix it.